# How to store rank of a user in a level with his score in SQL table

Tags: mysql, sql, rank

I'm pretty lost with all the SQL stuff, and I'd like to know how to implement a field that gives the player a rank depending of the level and the score he set.

[image: What I currently have]

[image: What I want]

I'm not that good with mySQL so that's why I'd like to know how should I do this.

Comment: Do you need to store this ranking in the table or just a query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For MySql 8.0 you can use [`rank()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_rank):

```
select 
  t.*, 
  rank() over (partition by t.level order by t.score DESC) `rank`
from tablename t
order by level, user
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kyov4cx4CfRxsJNm5FXWRr/1).
For earlier versions:

```
select 
  t.*,
(select count(*) from tablename where level = t.level and score > t.score) + 1 `rank`  
from tablename t
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8YQzavqirezHfLAVjSNvUd/1).
Results:

```
| level | user | score | rank |
| ----- | ---- | ----- | ---- |
| 1     | A    | 10    | 3    |
| 1     | B    | 15    | 2    |
| 1     | C    | 30    | 1    |
| 2     | A    | 20    | 2    |
| 2     | B    | 10    | 3    |
| 2     | C    | 40    | 1    |
```

Answer (score 1):

Calculated values are not something that you should be storing in the tables. Similar exmple is age. You do not store the age of the user, but its DOB. Values that keep changing are a complex issue when discussing database modeling.

There is a name for this type of a problem. It is called a slowly changing dimensions [wiki-link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slowly_changing_dimension). Therefore, I would advise you to implement any calculation logic in you application, rather then having it stored in the database.

But, if for some reason you must have it on your DB level, you can always create a procedure that gets executed at certain periods of the day. However, this might create situations that your data in the tables might not be accurate until the time that procedure gets executed [introduction to procedures](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/getting-started-with-mysql-stored-procedures.aspx).

Comment: First, thanks for your reply.

I understand the problem of calculed values and that's why I asked help, mostly. But now, how can I calculate the rank inside the application? I wanted the rank of each user on each level because I wanted to make a "global ranking" with all ranks of each level...

Comment: I assume you have some formula to calculate the rank.
You can create a function in the app that basically does the SELECT query but with  different WHERE clauses based on levels. Once you data is loaded in some sort of an array in the application's data layer, you can just perform the ranking process in the service layer. In such a manner, you would do part by part the calculation, and then you "push" the data onto the GUI, or in some other global list that will be later shown on the GUI.

Comment: Sounds doable. However, I wanted to do it like that: do a SELECT query that returns an array of the player's rank on each level, then proceed to the calculation thanks to this array... But here's the same problem: how do I get this rank even if it's not stored in the table? I saw that RANK() should be useful, but I have no idea how to use it. But is it needed anyway?

Comment: If the rank is something you are calculating, then you cannot fetch by it. You fetch by the level for example, and then you calculate the rank after you get your unsorted users. The rank is important to you only in the application anyways, so you do not need it in the DB level.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
select level,user,score,
rank() over(partition by level order by score desc) as rank
from Tablename;
```